# jquery plugin .imagecube trouble

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, effects

I am using the jquery plugin by http://keith-wood.name/imageCube.html.

it works as such but...

when my page loads the first image in the list(AT_logo.png) is displayed in the correct position i placed it but then it moves when the .imagecube starts. i noticed in the css it puts in, it is positioned absolute but my image is floating to the left in my class.

then also the 'imagecubeshading' class that gets added in is at the end not in between the images so it scrolls through them as if they were images.

my code is at the bottom. if more information is needed just ask.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/imagecube.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#logocube').imagecube();});
</script>

<div class="title_container">
    <div class="title_content1">
        <div class="title">title</div>
        <div class="sub_text">
            <a href="">Linked in</a>
            <b>Email</b>infp@email.com
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="logo" id="logocube">
        <img src="images/AT_logo.png" title="logo"/>
        <img src="images/AT_logo_bl_gr.png" title="logo"/>
        <img src="images/AT_logo_bl_wh.png" title="logo"/>
        <img src="images/AT_logo_gr_wh.png" title="logo"/>
        <img src="images/AT_logo_wh_bl.png" title="logo"/>
        <img src="images/AT_logo_wh_gr.png" title="logo"/>
   </div>

    <div class="title_content2">
        <div class="title" style="float:right;;">title</div>
        <div class="sub_text" style="float:right;">sub text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
.title_container
{
width:1265px;
height:380px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
position:relative;
background-color:transparent;
}

.title_content1
{
 width: 505px;
 height: 330px;
float: left;
background-image: url(/images/title_content_left.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
z-index:1;
}

.logo
{
width: 214px;
height: 198px;
float: left; 
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 162px;
margin-bottom: 72px;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
}

#logocube
{
width:214px;
height:198px;
}   

.title_content2
{
width: 505px; 
height: 330px;
float: right; 
background-image: url(/images/title_content_right.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sj5H/) from your code, but it looks fine to me. We may need more info about your surrounding code/markup.

Comment: i have updated the script so it has the surrounding divs and the container of them all.